# rangos aleatorios con PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Me podrían ayudar con los rangos aleatorios?, tengo mi BD en mysql y y tengo una tabla llamada "personas" la cual tiene un "id" "edad" "nombre "apellido", y quiero sacar rangos sobre la edad,

ejemplo: entre 20 y 30
entre 30 y 40

```php
$sql = " SELECT
SUM(IF (edad BETWEEN 20 AND 30, 1, 0)) as empleado_nuevo,
SUM(IF (edad BETWEEN 30 AND 40, 1, 0)) as empleado_a,
SUM(IF (edad BETWEEN 40 AND 50, 1, 0)) as empleado_v,
FROM personas;";
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve]? Así como esta, no me queda claro que es lo que estas necesitando ni el resultado esperado.

Comment: Creo que lo que tu buscas es obtener la cantidad de registros entre ciertos rangos, pero eso no es aleatorio estrictamente, (aleatorio es un numero al azar), yo creo que lo que tu necesitas es un GROUP BY mediante el cual podrías filtrar por rangos

Comment: rpailao asi es amigo, eso es lo que busco, es que tengo ese codigo de arriba pero no muestra ningun dato

Comment: Podrías empezar haciendo pruebas directo en la base, para ver si retorna algo luego te vas a ver el código, echale un ojo a este Fiddle por si te sirve de orientación. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f637c/4)

Comment: `as empleado_v,` esa coma final está mal, seguramente ahí esta tu error.

Comment: muchas gracias @rpaillao efectivamente estaba en un error, le agradezco la correción, saludos